# trying to make a command and show when it was sent in timestamp format

Tags: python, discord

I've tried a few different ways and still can't figure it out.

```
def get_message_timestamp():
    timestamp = datetime.now().timestamp()
    return timestamp

message_timestamp = get_message_timestamp()
@bot.tree.command(name="test", description = "test")
async def test(ctx:discord.Interaction):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="", description=f"hello world, <t:{message_timestamp}:R>", color=discord.Color.green())
    await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with this?

Comment: [image](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1044056386373431416/1131745661977645136/image.png) it dont show in timestamp @mkrieger1

Comment: no errors tho so idk whats wrong